Hides paths while adding arguments in Wix installer and using them in the application
I have a WIX installer in which I have added an argument which would be furnished when setup is installing and application is opened, it will read the argument and run accordingly.
I have added this functionality for shortcut of the application.
But, I notice that shortcut properties of application has the argument written, which a user can directly edit and open the application according to a different argument.
How can I pass that argument without it being shown in the shortcut properties.
<Component Id="AppShortcut" Guid="{Some GUID}">  
  <Shortcut Id="AppShortcut"
        Name="$(var.ProdName)"
        Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]MyApp.exe"
        Directory="ProgramMenuFolder"
        Arguments="[VAR]"
        WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"
        Icon="icon.ico"
            />
</Component>


You can't hide arguments from the shortcut dialog. As a more hidden way to communicate data from the setup to your application, I suggest to write the argument to a file within the application's install folder (e. g. using IniFile element) and read that from the application.
